# How can I use multiple mounted folders in KVM?

Tags: mount, virtual-machine, kvm

I have a KVM-guest, where 5 folders should be also accessible on the host machine under a single folder. How can I do that with a single mount point?

The folders on the vm are:

```
/var/log/apache2
/var/www/websitename/uploads
/var/log/mysql
```

And I thought to put them under

```
/var/lib/libvirt/nameOfVm
```

Comment: If you created /var/lib/libvirt/nameofvm on the host, then shared that directory with NFS (appropriately restricted by IP or otherwise for your environment), you could just mount it in in the vm at all three locations and it would drop all files in the one directory if that's what you're after. Or just create /var/lib/libvirt/nameofvm/apache2 and so forth and share each directory. I do something similar on my own virtual network.